# How to run no more than n parallel subshells

Tags: shell-script, subshell, parallelism

I am trying to run subscripts from a main script, but I want to make sure than no more than ***n*** subscripts run at the same time.

The following simplified example illustrates.

Each subscript creates a dummy file in RAM (`/dev/shm/`) with a name made of a unique timestamp, and deletes it once done.

The main script counts the number of dummy files in `/dev/shm/` originating from the subscripts, and doesn't (shouldn't) launch a new subscript if 2 or more of them are already running.

However, the main script seems to ignore the while condition, and launches all 5 subscripts at once.

What's wrong with my code?

mainscript.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
for counter in $(seq 1 5)
do
        while [ $(ls -1 /dev/shm/|grep "script044"|wc -l) -ge 2 ]
        do
                sleep 0
        done

        xterm -e "bash script044.txt" &
done

exit
```

script044.txt (subscript)

```
#!/bin/bash

tempfilename="script044_"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)_${RANDOM}
echo > /dev/shm/${tempfilename}

for counter in $(seq 1 $(shuf -i 10-45 -n 1))
do
        sleep 1
        printf "${counter}\r"
done

rm /dev/shm/${tempfilename}

exit
```

Answer (score 3):

(Convention - `.txt` are just plain text files.  `.sh` files are shell script files.).

Your mainscript.txt script has a race condition.  Specifically the while loop starts its next iteration before the script044.txt script is able to create the temporary file.  In fact the whole loop is iterated through before any of these files get created.

A more robust way to deal with this sort of thing is to forget the temporary files and use the shell builtin `wait` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid_count=0
for counter in $(seq 1 5)
do
    xterm -e "bash script044.txt" &
    if (( ++pid_count > 2 )); then
        wait -n
        ((pid_count--))
    fi
done
```

This increments a counter every time a subprocess is started.  If the counter is greater than 3 then we `wait` for the next subprocess to finish.  When `wait` returns, we then decrement the counter and go around again to start the next xterm.

You can remove all the `tempfilename`-related lines from the script044.txt - they are no longer needed.

---

As @chepner points out, the required `-n` option is only available in bash 4.3 or later.

Comment: Nice, but you should use `$!` instead of `$$`?

Comment: Note that `wait -n` was only introduced in `bash` 4.3.

Comment: @yaegashi Yes, of course!  Surprisingly it seemed to work with `$$` too, though that doesn't totally make sense

Comment: @yaegashi Ah - now I see it  - `wait -n` just waits for the next sub-process to end - we don't need the pid list at all!

Comment: But that waits on all of them, right? Like, if you have 5 bg'd children, the next loop iteration does not happen until all 5 die, yeah?

Comment: Oh duh, nevermind. Only one a time. Seems weird.

Comment: @mikeserv Thats the point of the `-n` option. Without it we wait for all background child processes to finish.  With it we just wait for the next one to finish.

Comment: Yeah, I picked it up after a while - I'm a little slow. It seemed like a weird question to me at first.

Comment: Answer is actual bogus. Counter and running jobs are not in sync. Don't use this. Obvious problem: counter does not reliable decrement if a bg job is done. After the wait to the next wait is a racecondition, where more than one job is able to finish, so you lose max-jobs over time.

Comment: @zstegi You're right - there is a possibility of a race condition there if a subprocess completes before the `wait -n`.  I had considered doing something like `job_pids=( $( jobs -p ) ) ; if (( ${#job_pids[@]} > 2 )); then ...` instead.  But there is still a possible race condition that the last subprocess finishes between the `jobs` and the `wait`.  Do you have any helpful suggestions to make this answer *unbogus*?

Comment: Ad-hoc I know only a polling solution, but I wouldn't recommend it anyway: while [ $( jobs | wc -l ) -gt 2 ]; do sleep 0.1; done

Answer (score 2):

While it won't help if you are aiming for a shell-only solution, GNU parallel provides a [`sem`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html) command that can help with this exact situation.

The following (untested since I don't have your script) should run your job 5 times, but only 2 at a time, waiting to exit at the end:

```
LIMIT=2
for i in {1..5}; do
    sem -j $LIMIT 'term -e "bash script044.txt"'
done
sem --wait
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want IPC. Rather than looping over sleep and doing a test each time you do, you can just wait for the child process to tell when its done. This is what pipes are for.

You can have the child processes report to the parent. Open a pipe and share it with them. When they're through, they just need to let the parent know.

```sh
sub()(  trap "echo >&9" 0
        sleep 5
)
eval    "exec 9<>"<(echo);i=0
until   [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 5 ]
do      sub & read na <&9
        date +%S:%t"$i"
done
```

I open it using process substitution. If you can't do this in your shell, you can use instead:

```
mkfifo pipe; exec 9<>pipe; rm pipe; echo >&9
```

Now the initial `echo` puts one line in the pipe - in both cases. That puts you one wait process ahead from the start - which means you'll run two concurrent processes all along. This script uses `date` to report on the seconds between each `sub()` call. Here's the output:

```
34: 1
39: 2
39: 3
44: 4
44: 5
```

There. Now as you see, every 5 seconds a child dies and when it does it `echo`'s a line to the pipe that `read` is currently blocking on. As soon as `read` find's a newline in input, it can quit what it's doing and start over.

You just need to put a `trap` in your script_044 which instructs the child processes to call out to father when they're through.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to accomplish this, is to use xargs

```
printf "%s\n" {1..5} | xargs -P2 -n1 -i xterm -e '/bin/echo Job {}; bash'
```

printf is only there to fill xargs with values. xargs default replace-str is {} if the -i flag is used. Please read the manpage of xargs to get more detail informations. This should work with the GNU tools and bash as shell.

```
xargs flags: 
-P     Run up to max-procs processes at a time.[…]
-n     Use  at most max-args arguments per command line.[…]
-i/-I  Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.[…]
```

Comment: generic regarding the use not the used tool(s).

Answer (score 0):

Insert some delay just after launching a new instance of `xterm`...

```
        xterm -e "bash script044.txt" &
        sleep 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
seq 1 5 | parallel -j2 -N0 'xterm -e "bash script044.txt"'
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Note: Ole Tange (the author of this post) is the author of GNU parallel.